# AngularJS Include scripts based on current route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS app I have over 15 controllers, services...etc which I am currently including them all in index.html which include ng-view, so I was wondering is there a way to include only the controllers, services of the current loaded route? Instead of including all controllers, services for all routes all the time? Thanks

Comment: Lookup using requireJS with angularJS

Comment: @dave Isn't there any AngularJS approach? RequireJS looks great but I am hoping for more of an AngularJS approach to solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: Angular does not support lazy loading as of version 1.x, it will be from 2.0... for now, you can take a look at https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-1.x-async-hack or https://github.com/doodeec/ng-1.x-async-hack/tree/multiple_lazy_files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AngularJS approach is to load them all beforehand.  You could *probably* do something like

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/home',
    {
        templateUrl: '/app/views/home.html',
        resolve: resolveController('/app/controllers/homeController.js')
    });
```

And then resolveController would return a promise.It would load the scriptwith the controller and resolve the promise once the load is complete.  Something like

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        var resolveController = function(path) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = path;
            script.onload = function() {
                $scope.$apply(deferred.resolve());
            };
            document.body.appendChild(script);
            return deferred.promise;
        };
        $routeProvider.when('/home', function() { /*...*/ } );
    }
);
```

There could be syntax errors as I haven't even tried this, but this is what I would probably try if I wanted to do it.

Comment: In which controller  funtion  resolveController(path) has to be written ?

Comment: I get an error at `$scope.$apply(deferred.resolve());` : `$scope.$apply is not a function` and before this I get `angular-1.5.8.js:13920 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object`. I'm using ui-router